# Using ampersand in URLs

Tags: php, url, url-encoding

I have a static HTML page and I'm converting it to CMS Concrete5, the URL of this page has an ampersand `'&'` in it, so what I want is make the new URL in CMS the same as the static HTML page.

The desired page URL is `www.domain.com/Fitness/WT&End`

When I was creating the page, I tried to put the `'&'` in the URL slug but it gets converts it to a hyphen `-`

I also tried to put `%26` in the URL slug but it gets converted to `'-26'`. I also tried `&amp;` and also it didn't work and gets converted to `-amp`

I searched for previous questions on the same topic, some people said to try http://php.net/urlencode or http://php.net/rawurlencode, but I'm not sure how to do that because my PHP knowledge is limited

The function that I want is to let me create a page with this URL `www.domain.com/Fitness/WT&End` without converting the `&` to any other characters

**Edit:**

this is the code inside the .htaccess file

```
# -- concrete5 urls start --
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /concrete/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# -- concrete5 urls end --
```

Comment: This is not standard behavior (& being converted to -) and I think the issue sits within a `rewrite` rule inside `.htaccess`

Comment: @IsThisJavascript I added the code inside .htaccess file, is there something that is causing this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can use urlencode as following:

```
public function encode_url($url){
       reuturn urlencode($url);
}
```

and then making call to this function by passing your url as

```
$new_url=encode_url("your url");
```